# Google API Where() and When() namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, google-api, visual-studio-2013, google-calendar-api

Im wondering what to add to my project (import? reference?) to be able to use Where()- and When()-methods for the Google calendar.

Code:

```
Where eventLocation = new Where();
eventLocation.ValueString = "South Tennis Courts";
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

When eventTime = new When(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
entry.Times.Add(eventTime);
```

Errors:

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Where' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error 3 The type or namespace name 'When' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

UPDATE:
Current imports:

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Calendar;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.AccessControl;
```

Comment: `Where` and `When` are terribly bad names for classes.

Comment: Click on `Where` or `When` in VS and try to have it suggest where to find it. If it can't find it, you probably don't have the right reference added yet.

Comment: Nonetheless its what google uses in its example: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet . But thanks for the constructive comment..

Comment: @HighCore, that's why namespaces were invented. :)

Comment: Do you have all the references from [the official example](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/calendar/Calendar.csproj)? That is, `Google.GData.AccessControl.dll` and the three others.

Comment: I believe so, I added my references in an update

Comment: Is it version 1.1.3.0 of the referenced assemblies, like in the example code?

Comment: It is version 2.2.0, maybe I need to dl the old versions, but should there not be a fx for these versions aswell?

Comment: Either way, it sounds like you need example code for 2.2.0 instead of 1.1.3.0. Maybe 2.2.0 is the v3 API?

Comment: This seems to be the latest version they have for this example, So Ill just dl 1.1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google API doc page for the `Where` class](https://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r900/docs/folder27/T_Google_GData_Extensions_Where.htm) lists the DLL that you need to add as a reference, and the namespace within that assembly:

> **Namespace:** Google.GData.Extensions
>
> **Assembly:** Google.GData.Extensions (in Google.GData.Extensions.dll)

This works correctly for me in VS2012, using the latest API download (2.2.0) from [this page](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list), dated June 2013.  MSI hardlink [here](https://google-gdata.googlecode.com/files/Google_Data_API_Setup_2.2.0.0.msi).

It's not an obvious location if you look at the list of DLLs installed as part of the API setup (the obvious guess would have been Google.GData.Calendar.dll).

Comment: The [official example code](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/clients/cs/samples/calendar/console/CalendarDemo.cs) uses `using Google.GData.AccessControl;
using Google.GData.Calendar;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;`, so it's probably one of those.

Comment: please look at the updated question, but thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks - I updated my answer to reference the correct DLL and namespace.